# Prolog separating lists

Tags: prolog

Hello is there any way to separate a list in Prolog into two other lists, the first includes everything before an element and the second everything after the element. For example

```
A=[1,2,3,5,7,9,0] and element=5
```

the two lists should be

```
A1=[1,2,3] and A2=[7,9,0]
```

I don't care about finding the element just what to do next

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's easy as

```
?- Elem = 5, A = [1,2,3,5,7,9,0], append(A1, [Elem|A2], A).
```

*edit* to explain a bit...

append/3 it's a *relation* among 3 lists.

It's general enough to solve any concatenation on *proper* lists - when not there are *circular* arguments.

The comparison it's a plain unification, that take place on second argument. That must be a list beginning with Elem. Prolog list constructor syntax is `[Head|Tail]`. To make unification succeed, Elem must *match* the Head.

Comment: It works but can you give me a brief explanation how append works? I know that give a list1 and a list2 it concatenates them into one list. Also how the comparison takes place?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative method, illustrating how to handle it with list recursion:

```
split([E|T], E, [], T).
split([X|T], E, [X|LL], LR) :-
    X \== E,
    split(T, E, LL, LR).
```

Or better, if your Prolog supports `dif/2`:

```
split([E|T], E, [], T).
split([X|T], E, [X|LL], LR) :-
    dif(X, E),
    split(T, E, LL, LR).
```

Examples:

```
| ?- split([1,2,3,4,5], 3, L, R).

L = [1,2]
R = [4,5] ? ;

no
| ?- split([1,2,3,4,5], 5, L, R).

L = [1,2,3,4]
R = [] ? ;

(1 ms) no
| ?- split([1,2,3,4,5], 1, L, R).

L = []
R = [2,3,4,5] ? ;

no
| ?-
```

It is a sort of specialized twist on `append/3` as CapelliC showed.

Comment: @repeat thanks, yes, I agree. The reason I don't always use `dif/2` is because usually gravitate toward my gprolog installation which doesn't have `dif/2`. I've tried some implementation so of `dif/2` which didn't seem to do the same thing.